# How to export dataset from PostgreSQL to CSV on AWS so that users can download it?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an API where users can query some time-series data. But now I want to make the entire data set available for users to download for their own uses. How would I go about doing something like this? I have RDS, an EC2 instance setup. What would my next steps be?

Comment: Read: [PostgreSQL S3 Exporting to a CSV file that uses a custom delimiter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html#postgresql-s3-export-examples-custom-delimiter)

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario and without any other data or restrictions given, I would use S3 bucket in the center of this process.

1. Create an S3 Bucket to save the database/dataset dump.
2. Dump the database/dataset to S3. ( examples: [docker](https://github.com/ianneub/pg_dump-to-s3), [lambda](https://github.com/jameshy/pgdump-aws-lambda) )
3. Manually transform dataset to CSV or use a Lambda triggered on every dataset dump. (not sure if pg_dump can give you CSV out of the box)
4. Host those datasets in a bucket accessible to your users and allow access to them as per case:

- You can create a [publicly available bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/) and share its HTTP URL.
- You can create a [pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) to allow limited access to your dataset

S3 is proposed since its cheap and you can find a lot of readily available tooling to work with.